# PHP form generates "Object not found" but still submits form data

Tags: php, forms

I've got a simple php form for client info that when submitted, generates an object not found 404 error. The information I submitted is still being sent to the db successfully so I'm not sure why I'm seeing this error. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<?php
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  $database='clientinformation';
  if (!$link)
  die('Failed to connect to Server'.mysql_error());
  $db=mysql_select_db($database, $link);
  session_start();
  if(!$db)
  die('Failed to select Data Base '.mysql_error());

if(isset($_GET['process']))
   {
    $query = "Insert INTO `client_reg` (ClientName, Address, CNICNumber, MobileNumber, TelephoneNumber, CompanyName, ClientStatus, RegisterDate) values('$_POST[ClientName]', '$_POST[Address]','$_POST[CNICno]','$_POST[Mobileno]', '$_POST[Telephoneno]', '$_POST[Companyname]', '$_POST[Clientstatus]', '$_POST[RegisteredDate]')";
    //echo $query; exit;
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(!$result)
    {
     $msg = "not Inserted";

    }
    else
    {
     $msg = "Inserted";
     header("location:ClientList.php?m=".$msg);
    }
   }
?>
```

Comment: `ClientList.php` the file not found or mismatching in filename.

Comment: does `Clientlist.php` exist on your server? Remember that unix servers are case sensitive. if it's `clientlist.php` on the drive, you'll get a 404

Comment: Don't use mysql extension.  Use mysqli or PDO.  (I don't understand why so many people keep using mysql_* when it's been advised against for more than three years and is now officially deprecated.)

Comment: @MarcB please make your comment an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `Clientlist.php` exist on your server? Remember that UNIX servers are case sensitive. If it's `clientlist.php` on the drive, you'll get a 404

Answer (score 0):

404 error - "404 Not Found" web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link;

```
 `ClientList.php` the file not found or mismatching in filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this convention :

```
$_POST["name"])
```

Store value after submit form:

```
$clientName=$_POST['ClientName'];
$Address=$_POST['Address'];
$Mobileno=$_POST['Mobileno'];
$Telephoneno=$_POST['Telephoneno'];
$Companyname=$_POST['Companyname'];
$Clientstatus=$_POST['Clientstatus'];
$RegisteredDate=$_POST['RegisteredDate'];
```

Now use this value in your query,hope it will work.